# DOS batchfile is skipping FOR delims

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, csv

I'm trying to parse a text file, and it's working apart from skipping a column if it's empty.
Here's the file format:

```
206695844   66583369    L   CAT 1   1   4144042 214857      64378180    L   4144039 214853  Y
206669467   127810625   R   CAT 38  1   4136724 213413      724749204   R   4136727 213420  Y
206445106   65588013    L   CAT 4   1   4139084 210381      64363708    L   4139082 210372  Y

                                                         ^
                                                    empty column
```

As you can see, there are 14 columns, each seperated by a tab character.

My parsing line is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,5,7,8,9" %%i in (datafile.txt) DO (
   echo %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n >> outputDatafile.txt
)
```

The problem is it's skipping the 9th column (blank in example), and using the 10th instead, as in:

```
206695844   66583369    1   4144042 214857  64378180
```

I *want* that 9th column - even if empty!

I've also tried using an explicit tab character as a delimiter, because the help for FOR says:

**delims=xxx

- specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the default delimiter set of space and tab**:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,5,7,8,9* delims= " %%i in (datafile.txt) DO (
                                   ^tab
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

jeb got it - thanks!

to spit out the result to my file, i just use:

```
echo (!col1!%tab%!col2!%tab%!col3!%tab%!col4!%tab%!col5!%tab%!col6!) >> outputFile.txt
```

Comment: Are you really using MS-DOS? The FOR /F is only supported in modern Windows implementation of the "batch language"

Comment: ah, well, possibly a good point. This is running in a cmd shell on Win 7. That's a new flavour, is it? I should remove the tag?

Comment: I removed the tags and added the Windows-7 tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delim mechanism works the way that one ore more consecutive delims are reduced to a single delim, that's why you can't get an empty column this way.

But in your case it seems easy to replace the delims with a delim and a none delim character.
Like:
`set "line=#!line:<TAB>=<TAB>#!"`

Then each column is prefixed by a `#`, so you can get even "empty" columns.
You only need to remove always the first character.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "tab=   "
FOR /F "delims=" %%L in (datafile.txt) DO (
  set "line=%%L"
  set "line=#!line:%TAB%=%TAB%#!"
  for /F "tokens=1,2,5,7,8,9 delims=%TAB%" %%1 in ("!line!") DO (
    echo %%1, %%2, %%3,  %%4, %%5, %%6
    set "col1=%%1"
    set "col1=!col1:~1!"
    echo(!col1!
  )
)
```